# "You have made too many incorrect reviews" What?

Tags: support, bug

I have been banned from reviewing for having too many incorrect reviews. What? Most of my "attention" reviews I passed, and I was about to edit an answer. It said the question didn't exist? I just go back a the page and "You did not pass!" then I got that "you are banned from reviewing" thing. Can this be undone?

Answer (score 9):

The ban you have trigged is part of the automated auditing system that all reviewers (even moderators) are passed through. You are presented with a post that was already dealt with by the community. If your remedy differs from the community's, you fail the audit.

Fail too many times and you get an automated ban for an amount of time.

Your current ban expires in 2 days.

Comment: But i only did like 3 fails.

Comment: @StarOS Three fails is a lot, audits aren't that common, also was it three failed audits in a row? in that case the ban was without doubt justified. You don't have to review everything, if in doubt just choose `skip` and move on.

Comment: 3 failed audits in a row? No, that's total.

Comment: @StarOS AFAIK, even 3 fails, the system calculates it as `x fails in y days`